# Run command on all files in directory in parallel

Tags: bash

I have a directory containing multiple files. These files are coming via a network location; the source is sending these file via `scp` command. I have a batch command that will run for each of these incoming files; this command runs for around 5-6 hours.

I am trying to run below command in by linux box

```
find  Documents/wget/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec btaudip '{}' \;
```

My goal is to start the batch program for all files in the directory simultaneously. but, the above command only run for one file at a time. So, for this I changed this command as below. but it failed.

```
find  Documents/wget/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec btaudip '{}' & \;
```

How should I change the my command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that `find` gathers all arguments after the `-exec` option up to the first semicolon and then runs (*exec*) the resulting command, without passing them to a shell.
With your modifications, the final command generated by `find` is something like:

```
btaudip FNAME '&'
```

Therefore at each run `btaudip` is passed two parameters: the current file name (as found by `find`) and an ampersand.

To achieve what you want, you need to invoke a shell to process the '&' correctly, for example by using the following command:

```
find  Documents/wget/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "btaudip '{}' &" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `find` has this kind of job control; it is not a shell, and while it is able to spawn shells, the shells would run in sequence. Commands run asynchronously in those shells would run in sequence as a result.

Instead, you can rewrite this as a shell loop:

```
for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] || continue; btaudip "$f" & done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using above suggestions and improvisong I made a script file to convert all the PDF files in a folder and move to respective folders

ConvertPDFtoJPG.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
mkdir ConvertedJPG
for f in * 
do 
echo "converting" $f
pdftoppm -jpeg -rx 300 -ry 300 "$f" JPG
echo "moving converted JPG to " $f "\n"
mkdir "./ConvertedJPG/$f"
mv *.jpg "./ConvertedJPG/$f/"
done
```

you can create this file by opening terminal in the folder and using these commands

```sh
touch ConvertPDFtoJPG.sh
chmod ./ConvertPDFtoJPG.sh +x
gedit ./ConvertPDFtoJPG.sh
```

paste the code in the text editor

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
mkdir ConvertedJPG
for f in * 
do 
echo "converting" $f
pdftoppm -jpeg -rx 300 -ry 300 "$f" JPG
echo "moving converted JPG to " $f "\n"
mkdir "./ConvertedJPG/$f"
mv *.jpg "./ConvertedJPG/$f/"
done
```

close editor

run in  terminal
`./ConvertPDFtoJPG.sh`